# Styling infiniteHits with Algolia search

Tags: css, algolia

I have an Algolia search widget set up in my site, however the results all have their list number next to them.  How do I style this to remove the numbers?

The docs have this under cssClasses.

```
instantsearch.widgets.infiniteHits({
  // ...
  cssClasses: {
    root: 'MyCustomInfiniteHits',
    list: [
      'MyCustomInfiniteHits',
      'MyCustomInfiniteHits--subclass',
    ],
  },
});
```

So I tried something like this.

```
instantsearch.widgets.infiniteHits({
  // ...
  cssClasses: {
    list: [
      'list-style: none',
    ],
  },
});
```

but the numbers still appear.

My widget is inside of a Django template if that helps and I am using instantsearch.js.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I actually figured it out.  The string that you include inside of

```
list: [
    'customClass'
]
```

is the class that is applied to the element.  So you can then just add styling to your stylesheet.